# create local movie out of `CVPixelBufferRef` which gets trimmed at the beginning after some time

Tags: gpuimage, ciimage, cvpixelbuffer

I do have lots of `CVPixelBufferRef` which I would like to append to a movie in "real time", i.e. I get 50 - 60 `CVPixelBufferRef` per second (as they are frames) and would like to create a local video out of it.

Even better would be if I could have that video "floating", which means that it should always be two minutes long; as soon as I have a two minute video it should start to get trimmed at the beginning.

(How) is this possible?